# custom sort posts in archive/taxanomy page

Tags: posts, wp-query, archives, sort

I want to override the default sort order of posts in archive and taxonomy pages. what hooks should I implement?

Comment: Use the search on this site for a starting point. After 22 questions we expect a higher quality.

Comment: all searches showed how to write a custom query.. what i want is actually override the main wp_query

Comment: and i am not posting questions to please you. I am posting questions because I want answers obviously.

Comment: This site has standards for both asking and answering questions. See [ask] and [answer]. Second, this site is public. Your questions are not addressed to anyone inparticular and requests for question improvement are a valid use of comments per site standards.

Comment: I obviously searched before posting(who doesn't?) Anyway i got the answer. Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put something along these lines in your functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_get_posts' );

function custom_get_posts( $query ) {

if( is_category() || is_archive() ) { 
$query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'name';
$query->query_vars['order'] = 'ASC';
}

return $query;
}
```

[reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467031/change-default-wordpress-query-to-orderby-title) (see the second answer)